# Automatic writing text to the console using Node.js

Tags: node.js, ssh, console, automation

I need to clone GitHub repository using SSH and Node.js script:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

exec('git clone git@github.com:jquery/jquery.git',
    function (error, stdout, stderr) {
        console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
        console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
        if (error !== null) {
            console.log('exec error: ' + error);
        }
    }
);
```

If github.com not in `known_hosts` file, SSH forcing to enter "yes" on the question "Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?".

How can I automate the input of this text?

P.S. I know about `StrictHostKeyChecking=no`, but I need to clone repository without changing SSH config.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sure, that is entirely possible. When you call `child_process.exec`, it actually returns a `ChildProcess` Object. It contains an `.stdin` object which is an implementation of a `Writable Stream`, which you can pipe to / write to. Documentation on [ChildProcess.stdin](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_stdin), also on [Writable Stream](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_writable).

Here is some example code that relates to your question:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

var cmd = exec('git clone git@github.com:jquery/jquery.git', function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    // ...
});

cmd.stdin.write("yes");
```

Answer (score -1):

You could [pass in yes](https://serverfault.com/questions/447028/non-interactive-git-clone-ssh-fingerprint-prompt) prior to your git clone command.

`exec('yes | git clone git@github.com:jquery/jquery.git'...`

Comment: This doesn't put `yes` into STDIN, it executes the command "yes" and pipes that output.

Comment: I think you meant `exec('echo "yes" | git clone...')`