# How to respond to openssl prompts in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I am trying to remove password from a private key file using `openssl` with node js.

The node js code is:

```
cmd = exec('/usr/bin/openssl', [
    'rsa',
    '-in',
    `${process.cwd()}/privkey.pem`, '-out', `/home/pratik/newPrivateKey.pem`
]);
cmd.stdin.write("password", 'utf8');
```

I referred to [this SO](http://%3Ca%3Ehttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/25694884/automatic-writing-text-to-the-console-using-node-js/25695188%3C/a%3E) question. But in my case, on console I just see `true` as output. No file is created. What I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `child_process.spawn`, and then forward its stdin and stdout through your Node script using `{ stdio: "inherit" }`.

```
const child_process = require('child_process');
const openssl = child_process.spawn('openssl', [
  'rsa',
  '-in',
  "/Users/my_user/.ssh/my_key", '-out', "/Users/my_user/.ssh/unlocked_key"
], { stdio: "inherit" });
```

Or, for a non-interactive version, where you don't want it to prompt for the password:

```
const child_process = require('child_process');
const password = "somepassword";
const openssl = child_process.exec('openssl', [
  'rsa',
  '-in', "/Users/my_user/.ssh/my_key",
  '-out', "/Users/my_user/.ssh/output_key",
  '-passin', `pass:${password}`
]);
```

Comment: Can you give me a working example of my code? Because when I modified code as ```cmd = spawn('/usr/bin/openssl', ['rsa', '-in', `${process.cwd()}/privkey.pem`, '-out', `/home/pratik/newPrivateKey.pem`]); cmd.stdout.on('data', (data) => { cmd.stdin.write("password".toString(), 'utf8'); cmd.stdin.end(); });``` parent node process freezes. Any suggestions?

Comment: Here is something to get you started: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27458502/how-to-run-interactive-shell-command-inside-node-js It involves setting up a buffer variable, listening to "data" and possibly "end" events, and also forwarding STDIN between Node and the openssl command.

Comment: I tried that too. First `-i` is not option with `openssl` so interactive can not be interpreted. Second I am getting `cmd.stdout` as null. Any thoughts?

Comment: I was able to get this working in macOS by using `{ stdio: "inherit" }` which forwards stdin/stdout without doing the usual stream API song and dance; edited my answer to include the code, which hopefully will shed some light on your solution.

Comment: Was your `my_key` password protected? If the privatekey isn't password protected, then it works fine. With password protected, you need to use `stdin`. If it worked for you with password protected private key, can you please provide the entire code?

Comment: Yes, it was password-protected; yes, that is the entire code.  I just tested the output key, and that also worked.  Try to test with just the script I provided, and build up from there, into your actual application.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172633/discussion-between-pratik-gaikwad-and-ouni).